# Confused about 'respond_to' vs 'respond_to?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am learning Rails with railstutorial.org, and I am confused about something:
in [this chapter](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#sec:password_migration) the author tells us to do some testing in the console with the `respond_to?` method on a User object, and it works ok. But later, when we write the test for the `:encrypted_password` attribute, he uses `respond_to`.

Out of curiosity, I tried `respond_to` in the console, for a User object, and I get an error saying the method doesnt exist. Alas, if I try to write the test using `respond_to?` instead of `respond_to`, the test doesnt run.

Could someone explain me the difference, and why does the test only run with `respond_to`?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Ruby treats `?` and `!` as actual characters in a method name. `respond_to` and `respond_to?` are different. `?` indicates that this *should* respond with a true or false (by convention; this is not a requirement). Specifically:

`respond_to?` is a [**Ruby** method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) for detecting whether the class has a particular method on it. For example,

```
@user.respond_to?('eat_food')
```

would return true if the `User` class has an `eat_food` method on it.

`respond_to` is a [**Rails** method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) for responding to particular request types. For example:

```
def index
  @people = Person.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml { render :xml => @people.to_xml }
  end
end
```

However, in the RailsTutorial link you've provided, you're seeing an **RSpec** method `should` interacting with RSpec's [`respond_to`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.4.0/RSpec/Matchers#respond_to-instance_method) method. This wouldn't be available in your console, unless you run `rails console test`.

Comment: But if you read the example in the book, respond_to is not used with a request type, but with an attribute. Maybe Rails overrides the Ruby method so it also accepts attributes?

Comment: That's an RSpec method for testing: http://rspec.info/documentation/ ... it wouldn't be available in the console unless you set ENV to testing.

Comment: That makes sense, now I understand. Thank you Tim

Comment: I find it really wierd that Ruby creators decided to use the same statement name "respond_to" for two different things: discover if an object has a method OR respond to a request type. Oh yeah, there is an ? that makes them different. Wow. \o/

Comment: This wasn't Ruby creators at all. The first is a Ruby method. The second is a Rails method on ActionController. The third is an RSpec library method. ? and ! in Ruby have significance, so the difference between respond_to and respond_to? are equal to the difference between trim and trimr.

Comment: Lest future users be confused, the `?` on the end of a method name in ruby does *not* guarantee that the method will return a boolean. The `?` is just part of the method name, like any other character. That question mark methods should return a boolean is a well-established convention, but it is not universally followed. (see for instance https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5329 and the commotion caused when a question mark method did not return a bool)

Answer (score 4):

`respond_to?` is a Boolean evaluation. The `respond_to` is used (normally) for determining the display information.  [More information here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to).  The `respond_to?` checks to see if a method exists and returns true if it does and false if it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The test uses convenient helpers to be more user friendly.

Ruby is Ruby so using the good old `respond_to?` would work if you call it this way:

```
 @user.respond_to?(:encrypted_password).should be_true
```

There is another `respond_to` used in controllers but still nothing to do with those you already met.