# Check if a method/property is defined or not before calling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a newbie to RoR. I am trying to figure out how to check if a property is defined or not in the environment file(development.rb in this case).

We have a property defined in development.rb file, something like:

```
config.user = 'test-user'
```

Now in the code, I use it by calling:

```
 Rails.application.config.user
```

which gives me the required value.

But the problem is this configuration may be disabled sometimes. So, I want to check if this property is defined or not before assigning it. 
Something like

```
user_name = (if Rails.application.config.user is available)? 
             Rails.application.config.user : 'some_other_value'
```

I tried defined? and respond_to but did not work.

Any help/suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a `config.user` defined in every environment, but sometimes it has a value, and sometimes it doesn't, for example, it could be `nil` or an empty string, you can use [present?](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F):

```
Rails.application.config.user.present?
```

If it is not defined, you will get a `NoMethodError` in the case above, so you can rescue it:

```
begin
  user_name = Rails.application.config.user.present? ? Rails.application.config.user : 'some_other_value'
rescue NoMethodError
  user_name = 'some_other_value'
end
```

`respond_to?` should also work, just make sure you don't confuse it with `respond_to`, which [is a Rails method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849722/confused-about-respond-to-vs-respond-to). It might look something like this:

```
if Rails.application.config.respond_to?(:user) && Rails.application.config.user.present?
  user_name =  Rails.application.config.user
else
  user_name = 'some_other_value'
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using rails (it comes from `active_support` actually) every object will have a `try` method which also does what you want:

```
user_name = Rails.application.config.try(:user)
```

And ruby 2.3 brought us `&.`:

```
user_name = Rails.application.config&.user
```

Note that in both cases you can use the return value implicitly if `nil` should not be a valid user_name (because `try` and `&.` will return nil if `config` does not respond to `user`):

```
user_name = Rails.application.config&.user || 'Guest' # ruby >= 2.3.0
user_name = Rails.application.config.try(:user) || 'Guest'
```

If you are calling that piece of code more than twice (my rule of thumb), you should consider extracting it into an own method, e.g. `Application#user_name`.

**Correction**

In afterthought, I figured that `&.` will probably not work as expected here, because `config` is probably not nil. It really depends on the setting (is `user` configured, but empty? How is `config` implemented?). I keep that part of the answer though because it might be of interest for related problems (but remember: you'll need ruby 2.3 or later).

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer, I didn't know about `try` before. This seems like a better solution than rescuing an exception yourself.